# How to maintain session in worklight project?

Tags: android, session, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I have a login module and and now I want to logout. So how can I maintain session on client side. Is there any method in worklight for this? How can I generate session id for this on client side?

please help me out.

Comment: can anyone plz help..

Comment: Are you using custom login module? Did you tried `WL.Client.Logout(realm)` to logout and to get the client side session and session ID AFAIK there is no worklight javascript client side API. but you can verify by using `WL.Client.getLoginName(realm)`

Comment: @Bluewings I have server side request for login. Can you plz give mi example of WL.Client.Logout(realm) method

Comment: `WL.Client.logout("yourrealmname",{
    onSuccess: successCallback,
    onFailure: failureCallback
   });` you can find more in [this link](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fapiref%2Fr_wl_client_logout.html)

Answer (score -1):

You can use prefrence ... 
First save user id while login like this

```
    prefs.edit().putString(Constants.PREF_EMAIL, userName).commit();
```

and when next time while launching app do this....

```
    String email = prefs.getString(Constants.PREF_EMAIL, "guest");
    String password = prefs.getString(Constants.PREF_PASSWORD, "guest");


    if(!email.equalsIgnoreCase("guest") )
    {
    }
   else
    {
    }
```

Hope this will help u...

Comment: @ADT I want to generate session ID and maintain session.